# How to project a new data point to an existing coordinate system

Tags: r

I have a list of multi-omics data containing three matrices of genes/proteins/cells in rows, and individuals' samples in columns. The three matrices share the same samples.
I used Multiple CO-Inertia Analysis to project each sample on a CIA space (each sample is represented by three points based on transcriptomic,proteoimic, and cellular data).
Now, I have a new point in my original-dimensional structure, and I want to project it to the CIA coordinate system.

How do I get its new CIA-coordinates?

For reproducibility, I used the NCI60 data as an example.

```
library(omicade4)
data(NCI60_4arrays)

NCI60_4arrays.sub <- lapply(NCI60_4arrays, function(m) { return(m[,1: 
(ncol(m)-1)])})

mcoin <- mcia(NCI60_4arrays.sub, cia.nf=4)
```

For extraction of the samples coordinates in the CIA space:

```
sample.cia.coordinates <- mcoin$mcoa$Tli
```

How can I project a new data point, and get its CIA-coordinates?

A new data point for example:

```
new.point <- lapply(NCI60_4arrays, function(m) { return(m[,ncol(m)])})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option when you want to understand the calculations behind an analysis, is to create a sample analysis with low volume, for instance:

```
sample <- lapply(NCI60_4arrays[1:2], function(m) { return(m[1:7,1:5])})
sample_mcoa <- mcia(sample, cia.nf = 2)
```

and then try to understand how you pass from:

- 2 matrix 7x5

to:

- 1 matrix 10x2

It's probably severals matrix produces, one with `sample_mcoa$mcoa$axis`. I don't know if this helps you.